# How to dispatch action when user closes window/tab?

Tags: web-applications, react-redux

I'm using react-redux and have a chat application in the webapp. I want to be able to dispatch an action when the user closes the web browser, closes the tab, or changes to another website. I've looked around and tried this:

```
componentWillMount() {
   // run once before first render()
   this.props.initializeApp();
   this.dispatchActionOnExit = this.dispatchActionOnExit.bind(this);
}  
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener("unload", this.dispatchActionOnExit());
}
dispatchActionOnExit() {
   // dispatch the action when exit
}
componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener("unload", this.updateWindowDimensions);
}
```

But I don't understand what this line does:
`this.dispatchActionOnExit = this.dispatchActionOnExit.bind(this);`
Also, I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

so the line `this.dispatchActionOnExit = this.dispatchActionOnExit.bind(this);` simply binds the `this` context of whichever react components you have this code in. So that no matter where/when you call `dispatchActionOnExit` its `this` context will still be to the react component where you bound it. [See MDN Documentation on Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).